# Reason about auxuliary constructors in scala

Tags: scala

I have class methods to define auxiliary constructors in the case of python and the semantics are straightforward

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
 
    # a class method to create a
    # Person object by birth year.
    @classmethod
    def fromBirthYear(cls, name, year):
        return cls(name, date.today().year - year)
person2 = Person.fromBirthYear('pythonman', 1996)
```

The class method actually returns an instance of the class. Neat and sits well with the rest of the python. **Dont need to memorize any new fact about python except for what a class decorator does to a method of a class**

In scala, I have the last statement of the method as the return value

Can you help me understand what is happening with the auxiliary constructor in the case of scala? How to think about it given you have to necessarily run the constructor of the original class as the very first line of the auxiliary constructor method

The following does not work

```
import java.time.*

// [1] the primary constructor
class Student(
  var name: String,
  var govtId: String
):
  private var _applicationDate: Option[LocalDate] = None
  private var _studentId: Int = 0

  // [2] a constructor for when the student has completed
  // their application
  def this(
    name: String,
    govtId: String,
    applicationDate: LocalDate
  ) =
    _applicationDate = Some(applicationDate)
    this(name, govtId)
```

The following does

```
import java.time.*

// [1] the primary constructor
class Student(
  var name: String,
  var govtId: String
):
  private var _applicationDate: Option[LocalDate] = None
  private var _studentId: Int = 0

  // [2] a constructor for when the student has completed
  // their application
  def this(
    name: String,
    govtId: String,
    applicationDate: LocalDate
  ) =
    this(name, govtId)
    _applicationDate = Some(applicationDate)
```

Is this pattern just one more thing that I have to memorize for scala because that is the way it is written? Or, is there a rhyme or reason behind it? I would have expected at least the following signature and pattern from the auxiliary constructor

```
def this(
    name: String,
    govtId: String,
    applicationDate: LocalDate
  ): Person =
    //some code like _applicationDate = Some(applicationDate)
    this(name, govtId)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala, you'd probably be using a `case class` with immutable data as a starting point and `apply` method in the companion object for auxiliary constructors (actually these are more "factory methods" than "auxiliary constructors").

The auxiliary constructors that you used are kinda inherited from Java and not that much used in Scala.

This would look like this:

```scala
case class Student(
  name: String,
  govtId: String,
  applicationDate: Option[LocalDate] = None
)

object Student {

  def apply(name: String,
    govtId: String,
    applicationDate: LocalDate
  ): Student = {
    Student(name, govtId, Some(applicationDate))
  }

}
```

And then you can create instances like this:

```scala
Student("...", "...")
// Or:
Student("...", "...", Some(LocalDate.now())))
// Or:
Student("...", "...", LocalDate.now())
```

*Note that I didn't keep the `applicationDate` private like in your original example.*